# Permanently disable indexing in IntelliJ for specific folder (shared config)

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to disable indexing for `.cache` folders in a Maven project which is imported into IntelliJ IDEA (mentioned cache-folders exist in many sub-modules).

I know that I can disable indexing by marking it as "Excluded", but this setting is not shared across other users who use the same repository with IntelliJ.

I also know that Maven `target` folders are excluded, but the mentioned folders cannot be moved to `target`.

Is there a way to permanently exclude a folder from indexing and share this config with other users so it also persists when a new user sets up his IDE?

Preferred solution would be without checking `.iml` files into Git.

Comment: Did you already check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2028884/104891)? Does it help?

Comment: Yes, I have shorty looked at maven-idea-plugin, but I've not used it because the official site says "Apache Maven IDEA Plugin (RETIRED) Note: This plugin is retired. It is no longer maintained.". Since 2013.

Comment: In this case there doesn't seem to be a way to do it without committing the `.iml` files.